# C# running async tasks in sync context

Tags: c#, async-await

I don't have much experience in C# async.

Task - load bitmaps from the internet. Before, I was just loading them 1 by 1, in sync. Loading them in async would give results quicker. Down below, I made two examples, how I could get single image - `GetImage` and `GetImageAsync`. And for a list of Images, I would use `LoadImages` and `LoadImages2`.

`LoadImages` would run sync functions in async (all at the same time (?)), `LoadImages2` would run async functions in async and produce the same result (?).
The thing, that I don't fully understand - in `GetImageAsync` `await request.GetResponseAsync()`. Do I really need it? Is it a "better" way of doing the same thing? Are there really any difference between `LoadImages` and `LoadImages2`.

At the moment, I am thinking of choosing `GetImage` and `LoadImages` option. Also, I don't want to decorate every function with `async Task`, I only need to load these images in async.

```
public Bitmap GetImage(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        return new Bitmap(responseStream);
}

public async Task<Bitmap> GetImageAsync(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        return new Bitmap(responseStream);
}

private Dictionary<string, Bitmap> LoadImages(List<string> urls)
{
    Dictionary<string, Bitmap> images = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
    Task.WaitAll(urls.Select(url => 
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            images.Add(url, GetImage(url));
        })).ToArray());
    return images;
}

private Dictionary<string, Bitmap> LoadImages2(List<string> urls)
{
    Dictionary<string, Bitmap> images = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
    Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(url =>
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            images.Add(url, await GetImageAsync(url));
        })));
    return images;
}
```

Comment: `LoadImages2` looks like it returns before filling the images, because `Task.WhenAll` is not waiting but is returning an awaitable `Task`

Comment: Ok, it should then be `await Task.WhenAll(...)`, right ? But I cant use `await` in sync function. So then `Task.WhenAll(...).RunSynchronously()`?  These things bend my my in so many places. Anyway my main question is - does each image loading needs to be a task? I am already running them as tasks in `LoadImages`. So is there a difference?

Comment: You cannot use `await` without `async`. Generally, its recommended to go async all the way if you start it -> you load images async? Then your `LoadImages` method should be async to, unless you reach a point where asyncing is no longer an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some confusion around terminology and technology choices here.

> Before, I was just loading them 1 by 1, in sync. Loading them in async would give results quicker.

What you mean is *serial* versus *concurrent*, not *sync* versus *async*. Serial is one-at-a-time, and concurrent is multiple things at once. Synchronous code can be serial or concurrent, and asynchronous code can be serial or concurrent.

Secondly, *concurrency* versus *parallelism*. `Task.Run` is a form of parallelism, which is a way to achieve concurrency by adding threads to the problem. *Asynchrony* is a way to achieve concurrency by *freeing up* threads.

`LoadImages` is an example of using parallelism with synchronous code. The advantage of this approach is it keeps the top-level method synchronous, so none of the calling code has to change. The disadvantage is that it's wasteful in terms of resource use, and not a good conceptual fit for what's going on underneath (I/O-bound code is more naturally represented by asynchronous APIs).

`LoadImages2` is a mixture of parallel and asynchronous code which is a bit confusing. Asynchronous concurrency is more easily represented without threads (i.e., `Task.Run`). It's also more natural to return values rather than update collections as side effects. So, something like this:

```
private async Task<Dictionary<string, Bitmap>> LoadImagesAsync(List<string> urls)
{
  Bitmap[] result = await Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(url => GetImageAsync(url)));

  return Enumerable.Range(0, urls.Length).ToDictionary(i => urls[i], i => result[i]);
}
```

P.S. If you do decide to go with (the synchronous) `LoadImages`, you'll need to fix a race condition where the various parallel threads will all try to update the dictionary without locking it.

Comment: Yes! Concurrent loading was the right term! Example you gave, return `Task`. That means the function that calls this needs to be either `async` or handle the task in a different way. I am not sure, what would be the best one. Would `LoadImagesAsync(urls).Result` be fine? And about `LoadImages` race problems - should I then use `ConcurrentDictionary` ?

Comment: @Wish: No, you should use `await` instead of `Result`. `ConcurrentDictionary` is one approach; you could also just `lock` the regular dictionary.

Comment: Well, then `await` and `async` should bubble up to to the very top? That is not convenient and that is not what I want to do :/

Comment: @Wish: Yes, your choices are either to make it `async` and change your code, or use the parallel approach and use more resources.

Answer (score 0):

Since you insist on wrapping your call synchronously, you could try something along the lines of

```
private Dictionary<string, Bitmap> LoadImages(List<string> urls)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
    // start tasks, associate each task with its url
    var tasks = urls.Select(x => new { url = x, imgTask = GetImageAsync(x) });
    // wait for all tasks to complete
    Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(x => x.imgTask)).Wait();
    // transform the task results into your desired result format
    foreach (var item in tasks)
    {
        result.Add(item.url, item.imgTask.Result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, I'm not 100% confident that the `Task.WhenAll(...).Wait()` construct is completely deadlock-free in all situations. Avoiding deadlocks is the tricky part in switching between sync and async code. It would be better to make `LoadImages` async, as Stephan Cleary suggested. Its a common observation, that async code tends to "infect" your synchronous code and you have to code async all the way in the end.