# .Net Core Async Await - Not functioning as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm testing out the impact of using async and await as I understand it is supposedly able to run multiple calls by not blocking a thread.

I used this [link](https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-async-and-await-in-asp-net-what-do-these-keywords-mean/) as my reference

The following is my code on the controller :

```
[Route("api/email")]
public class EmailController : Controller
{
    private ContentManagement _contentManagement;
    public EmailController(ContentManagement contentManagement)
    {
        _contentManagement = contentManagement;
    }

    [HttpGet("async")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync()
    {
        DateTime cur = DateTime.Now;
        var name = await _contentManagement.GetNameAsync();

        return Ok($"Value   : {name} \nStarted  : {cur.TimeOfDay}\n Ended   : {DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay}");
    }
    [HttpGet("normal")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        DateTime cur = DateTime.Now;
        var name = _contentManagement.GetName();
        return Ok($"Value   : {name} \nStarted  : {cur.TimeOfDay}\n Ended   : {DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay}");

    }
}
```

The contentManagement class is exactly the same as provided in the link above.

I find that when I call the async web apis simultaneously, they perform exactly the same as the sync web api by performing the tasks sequentially.

Here are my results :

[image]

Anyone can provide feedback if I'm missing something or did something wrong?

UPDATE:
- So when I tried it on two devices, one on my computer and another on my phone, it seems that they run simultaneously (regardless if it's an async / await or just a normal sync method); 
- If it's on the same device, they run sequentially (as shown in the image above)

Comment: How exactly are you making the two requests *simultaneously*?

Comment: having two browsers and refreshing them at almost the same time

Comment: Are they the same browser (e.g. chrome/chrome) or different (e.g. chrome/edge)?

Comment: Same browser, chrome & chrome

Comment: Can you confirm the client computer is actually making simultaneous requests? You could try different methods of making the requests (different browsers, postman, from code) or e.g. [monitor the network traffic](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=44226)

Comment: @pere57 Ok. I've tried using Chrome, Edge + Postman, it looks simultaneous- the start timeoverlaps with one another; however, I'm slightly confused, the normal methods produce the same results

Comment: @JeremyLoh Yes, because the server is multithreaded. Have a look at the difference between asynchronous and parallel e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914053/c-sharp-running-async-tasks-in-sync-context/35916043#35916043)

Comment: @pere57 thanks . you've helped me understand better

Answer (score 3):

The main reason to run code async is to efficient the use of compute resources. Async is **not** a miracle line of code that will make some other code run faster.

In your case, when using async-await you will mainly efficient the use of threads in the thread pool.
Let's go through this by a simplified explanation.

If we take a look at your sync method first. When your thread reaches this line `var name = _contentManagement.GetName();` it will wait until it returns a name. In the processing time of GetName(), the thread will absoultely do nothing. It will just be locked waiting on the response.

The async method however; When your thread reaches this line `var name = await _contentManagement.GetNameAsync();` it will know that this method is marked `await` and then the thread is free to return to the thread pool to serve other stuff meanwhile the `GetNameAsync` processing. Then when the `GetNameAsync` is completed a thread will be served from the thread pool to continue the next line.

In this way we can perform the same logic but use less resources doing so (*we save thread time when processing external async calls*)

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for the response. When the code reaches the var name = await ..., the thread is released to the thread pool to run other items right.

Therefore, if I were to run two calls almost simultaneously, shouldn't both of them start almost the same time and end almost the same time. ie.

In the image above, on the left, when I refreshed, it started at 14:56:18, while , the result on the right starts only after the process on the left completes, at 14:56:21. Shouldn't the result on the right start somewhere in between 14:56:18 and 14:56:21?

Answer (score 1):

`async-await` will not make it faster. In fact, it will make it slower.

The real benefit is responsiveness. Releasing the UI thread, releasing the thread handling the web request, is etc.

You'll need more than one simultaneous request to see the difference.

Comment: Hi Paulo, thanks for replying. I know it doesn't make it faster but like you said it's releasing the thread. However, the image above shows the result when I refresh both pages 'almost' simultoneously - the thread doesn't seemed to be released but rather it's running sequentially

Comment: It's sequencial but, whether the thread is released or not depends on the implementation. What evidence do you have that the thread is being released or not?
Again, you need proper load tests to measure the difference. One is just not enough.

Comment: @pere57, where is that?